# If power of two matrices becomes equal then stays equal, with left-side row multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

During my research on probabilistic automata (in joint Computer Science and Mathematics), I could reduce a certain problem to a problem of matrices.

We are given the (element-wise) non-negative matrices $\Gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times r}$ and $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$. Denote

$$
E = \left\{ n \ \middle|\ \Gamma A^n \neq \Gamma B^n \right\}
$$

We know that there exists $k>0$ for which $k\notin E$, and we wish to prove that $E$ is not upper-bounded.

**In other words**, we know the following, for a given $n>0$:

$$
\begin{split}
\Gamma A^n &= \Gamma B^n &\quad \neq 0^{1\times r} \\
\Gamma A^k &\neq \Gamma B^k & \quad\forall 1\leq k < n
\end{split}
$$

The question is to decide whether the following situation is guaranteed:

$$
\varphi:= \exists k > n: \Gamma A^k \neq \Gamma B^k
$$

and I am optimistically trying to prove that it is true, but not succeeding and I need this community's help.

**Assumptions** that might be relevant:

- $A,B$ are not nilpotent.
- $n$ is as large as we want it (but constant and finite); i.e. if it helps, we can lower-bound $n$.
- $\Gamma,A,B$ satisfy: The sum of any row or column is at most 1.

**What I tried**:
In addition to the obvious, I tried proving that the set $\left\{A^\ell-B^\ell\right\}_{\ell\in\mathbb{N}}$ is of dimension $r^2$, thus showing:

$$
\Gamma A^n \neq 0
\implies \exists k: \ \Gamma A^n(A^{k-n}-B^{k-n}) \neq 0
\implies \varphi
$$

but it does not seem to have to be true.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ not nilpotent is probably not sufficient to guarantee this. At least, you'll need some semi-simplicity condition on the eigenvalue $0$ (in case that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$).

Comment: I think that I have a counter-example. Take $r=3$, $A=\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}$, $B=\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1\end{array}$, $\Gamma=(1,0,0)$. Then the $\Gamma A^n$ are $(0,0,1)$ for every $n>0$. The $\Gamma B^n$ are $(0,1,0)$ for $n=1$ and $(0,0,1)$ for any $n>1$. So, $\Gamma A^n = \Gamma B^n$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli: Yes, this examples demonstrates why one needs at least a semi-simplicity assumption on the eigenvalue $0$ (note that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ of your matrix $B$ is $1$, while the algebraic multiplicity is $2$). An even simpler example can be obtained by defining $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \oplus  (1)$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \oplus  (1)$ (with $\Gamma = (1,1,1)$). That's essentially a two-dimensional example, plus a trivial identity operation in the third component in order to avoid nil-potency.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli and Jochen Glueck, thank you both. Indeed the counterexample shows that these assumptions are not enough. I will try to learn more properties about the matrices from the original problem (of automata), of course after checking if the counterexample is valid there as well.